# Can I buy dependents their own health care plans?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, healthcare

I'm shopping for health care plans in the US.

I'm young and don't have any history of illness. I would be fine with a "bronze" plan. I would want my wife and child to be on a "gold" plan, however.

My wife and child are both marked as my dependents at the moment for taxes. Would it be possible to put them on their own plan even though they're my dependents, tax-wise? The goal is to save some money, since I don't need to be part of a gold plan.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can be on a different plan from your dependents.

The only real benefit to having everyone on the sale plan is the Family Deductible and Family Out of Pocket Maximum; which are both generally two times the Individual amounts for the same plan.

When you have just two people on the plan, this combination doesn't do anything.  When you have three or more people on the same plan you can realize the benefit of combining everyone under one plan.  Once one person in the family meets their deductible, any combination of the other family members can meet the rest up to the Family deductible; same goes for the out of pocket max.

Comment: Confirmed with the health insurance company that it's possible. Thanks for the help.